# Проверка длины пароля

Tags: python

В переменной password содержится пароль введенный пользователем.
Выведите фразу «Пароль слишком короткий» (без кавычек), если длина пароля меньше 6 символов.
Если длина от 6 до 8 символов, то выведите «Хорошо, но можно и лучше».
Если длина более 8 символов — «Пароль подходит».
Я написал таким образом:

```
password = "123456789" 
if len(password) < 6: 
  print("Пароль слишком короткий") 
elif len(password) > 6 < 8: 
  print("Хорошо, но можно еше лучше")
else: 
  if len(password) > 8: 
    print("Пароль подходит").
```

Помогите решить задачу.

Comment: надо писать не elif len(password) > 6 < 8: 

а elif len(password) > 6 and len(password) < 8:

Comment: Нафига сравнивать с 6 во второй ветке, если варианты в 0-5 символов уже обработаны первой веткой? Ну и то же с третьей веткой, нафига там вообще ещё один вложенный if? PS. А длина ровно в 8 символов так и вовсе не обрабатывается.

Comment: @SeryiBANANAN Ну, можно и без "and": `elif 6 <= len(password) <= 8:`.

Comment: @GrAnd в принципе да

Answer (score 6):

***Сокращённая версия:***

```
password = "123456789" 
if len(password) < 6: print("Пароль слишком короткий") 
elif len(password) <=  8: print("Хорошо, но можно еше лучше")
else: print("Пароль подходит")
```

Comment: Исправил, теперь нормально

Comment: Молодец) в одну строку уложишь? =) Не всегда количество строк отражает качество написанного кода) а скорей всего - никогда) Без негатива

Comment: В одну строку не любитель, там всё так напихано... =) Тут в принципе ещё понятно

Comment: О том и речь) легко читается => легко понимается => легко работать и респект от команды. А если еще всякие крючки и пасхалки оставляешь, то цены тебе нет=)

Comment: @Dmitry В одну строчку, говорите... Да пожалуйста: `print([text for n, text in {9: "Пароль подходит", 6: "Хорошо, но можно еше лучше", 0: "Пароль слишком короткий"}.items() if len(password) >= n][0])`. :))

Comment: @GrAnd Ну в Вас-то я не сомневался ;)

Comment: @GrAnd а кто сомневался? я - нет=)

Answer (score 5):

Тут в комментариях спрашивали про однострочник. Вот придумал такой способ:

```
print(["Пароль слишком короткий","Пароль подходит","Хорошо, но можно еше лучше"][-len(password[5:9])//3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Слегка подправил код, как уже указывали другие в комментариях, нет смысла повторно проверять условия в elif и else.
Дело в том, что если if сработал, то elif и else уже точно не будут отрабатывать.

```
password = "123456789" 
## Выведите фразу «Пароль слишком короткий» (без кавычек), если длина пароля меньше 6 символов
if len(password) < 6: 
    print("Пароль слишком короткий") 
#Если длина от 6 до 8 символов, то выведите «Хорошо, но можно и лучше»
elif len(password) <= 8: 
    print("Хорошо, но можно еше лучше")
#Если длина более 8 символов — «Пароль подходит»
else: 
    print("Пароль подходит")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Ответ очевиден:

```
password = "123456789" 
if len(password) < 6: 
  print("Пароль слишком короткий") 
elif len(password) > 6 and len(password) < 8: 
  print("Хорошо, но можно еше лучше")
else: 
  if len(password) > 8: 
    print("Пароль подходит")
```

Comment: Зачем так трудно? Всякие `and`-ы. К тому же почти этот ответ дал @АлексейОбухов